# Visual Studio: is there a way to include resources in a Build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, resources, release

I have a C++ Visual Studio project that depends on some resources (`.glsl` files).

Currently I have to copy and paste the resource directories each time I build the project, but that's quite unhandy.

I would like to know if there is a way to **make the building process automatically include the resource files** besides the generated `.exe`. If anyone could possibly provide some references too it would be appreciated, given that I can't find anything online.

---

The project structure is the following:

```
root
 |
 +-- resources
 |    |
 |    +- shaders
 |        |
 |        +- shader files (.glsl)
 |
 +- src files (.cpp/.h)
```

Current result after the release build:

```
Release
 |
 +- .exe
 +- .pdb
 +- DLLs
```

Desired result:

```
Release
 |
 +-- resources
 |    |
 |    +- shaders
 |        |
 |        +- shader files (.glsl)
 |
 +- .exe
 +- .pdb
 +- DLLs
```

#### Edit

As suggested by [Minxin Yu - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16764520/minxin-yu-msft), I've tried using the Post-build events, with the following command:

```
PowerShell Copy-Item -Path $(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\resources  -Destination  $(SolutionDir)x64\Release\ -Recurse
```

But the build fails with the following error:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: 02es, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Copy-Item : Impossibile trovare un parametro posizionale che accetta l'argomento
1>'Righi\Programmi\GitHub\Fondamenti-di-Computer-Graphics-M\laboratorio\02es\resources'.
1>In riga:1 car:1
1>+ Copy-Item -Path D:\Michele Righi\Programmi\GitHub\Fondamenti-di-Compu ...
1>+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
1>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
1>
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: The command "PowerShell Copy-Item -Path D:\Michele Righi\Programmi\GitHub\Fondamenti-di-Computer-Graphics-M\laboratorio\02es\resources  -Destination  D:\Michele Righi\Programmi\GitHub\Fondamenti-di-Computer-Graphics-M\laboratorio\x64\Release\ -Recurse
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "02es.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 9:23 AM and took 02,321 seconds ==========
```

Comment: Hi, is  your problem solved? Does  the powershell  work?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Hi, sorry for the delay and thank you again for the patience and for the help, I updated the question with the error I get while using the command you suggested. I had already tried it before using robocopy, but forgot to update the thread. Let me know if you would like to know further details

Comment: This problem is caused by spaces in the path. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  post build event in Project's properties's Build   Events.

E.g.

```
PowerShell Copy-Item -Path $(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\resources  -Destination  $(SolutionDir)x64\Release\ -Recurse
```

Update:
For path with spaces, combine "" and ''

```
PowerShell Copy-Item "-Path '$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\resources'  -Destination  '$(SolutionDir)x64\Release\' -Recurse"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've tried using robocopy: `robocopy "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\resources" "$(SolutionDir)x64\Release\resources" /s /e` and the resources get copied correctly but the build fails with error `MSB3073:  :VCEnd exited with code 1`

Comment: Hi， @mikyll98 I tested robocopy and it doesn't seem to work well with build events. (tested the same code on command line and Visual Studio). Please consider using the PowerShell script provided